# Hiding Address Bar in Mobile Safari With Reader Button Visible

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, ios6

Ok, so I'm using [the suggested window-scrollTo method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890003/how-to-remove-address-bar-in-safari-in-ios5) and it's working just swimmingly everywhere except for one little sticking point.

When Safari decides to show the "Reader" button figuring I might want to save my page for later reading, it keeps the address bar up for a full 5 seconds before finally hiding it like I asked. Kind of an eternity in UX time.

Is this an iOS 6 thing or did it also do this in iOS 5?  (I don't have a 5 device to test it on at the moment.)  Also, is there any way to get around it?

Comment: I found an iOS 5 device and the delay is still there but significantly shorter.  3s or so.

Comment: i can confirm that this started as of ios6 and has been working fine until ios5.

Comment: There seems to be no fix for this at the moment. The problem I am having is that the URL bar actually covers my content (H1) during these 5 seconds. Quite annoying and interferes with reading of the site :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked around quite a bit and there doesn't appear to be any way to disable the reader button. The only possible solution I found was to make your site less "readable" so Safari doesn't add the reader button. Exactly what makes a site "readable" is pretty murky.

Here's some research on what makes something "readable": http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader

Here's a method to make it less readable by putting your content in CSS: http://askmike.org/2012/12/a-hacky-way-to-remove-the-reader-button-in-ios-safari/

The bottom line seems to be that there is no solution. Hopefully Apple will add a meta tag to disable it or at least let us hide the address bar faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

I placed all content inside an ol tag.

```
<ol style = "padding:0;margin:0"> 
   my content
</ol>
```

From what I read elsewhere, the reader is partly triggered by the number of words on a page, but does not count words inside an ol.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the reader `button` by hiding the content that triggers it.

And then displaying that content 1s after the page loads.

For instance, hide all your `<p>` elements if they are triggering the reader `button`.