# HTML5 Game - Hide navigation bar/Adress bar? (ios7)

Tags: javascript, html, ios7

I wonder if there is a solution to the navigation bar problem in ios7? Where you can't hide it.
The window.scrollTo(0, 1) no longer works in ios7.

It activates as soon as i touch the lower or upper part of the screen.

There are a couple of these threads but they are a couple of months old, i wonder if a solution has arrived since then?

Is there any kind of workaround?

Links to previous threads.

[Impossible to hide navigation bars in Safari iOS 7 for iPhone/iPod touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793072/impossible-to-hide-navigation-bars-in-safari-ios-7-for-iphone-ipod-touch)

Comment: Maybe if you link to the threads you're talking about we could have more context for your question and help better.

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry. I have added a link to give you guys a better context.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Add this meta tag

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

And put this JS after DOM gets loaded(in ready)

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just add this**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

before  tag