# Famo.us and landscape orientation

Tags: famo.us

Is famo.us currently suitable for landscape oriented development ? I'm especially concerned in making it to work on iPhone. As I saw unfortunately the iOS < 7.1 safari takes a quarter of the height just for the navigation bar. Hiding it completely involves adding the app (webpage) to the main screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Famo.us is most certainly suitable for landscape oriented Design. The sizing feature of 'undefined' for Famo.us surfaces and the origin constraints on modifiers allow for designs to fit any number of device sizes and orientations.

Detecting an orientation change using only Famo.us can be done using something similar to the following..

```
Engine.on('resize',function(){
    size = context.getSize();
    if (size[0] > size[1]) {
        // landscape
    } else {
        // portrait
    } 

});
```

Comment: Have you tried on iPhone ? the navigation bar and footer takes a lot of place. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid this, as it does appear to be almost unusable. I'm still on 7.0.4, it did changed [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793072/impossible-to-hide-navigation-bars-in-safari-ios-7-for-iphone-ipod-touch) in iOS 7.1 but I haven't been able yet to try and check if it is usable

Comment: I see what you are saying.. Famo.us would have no control over the OS browser. If the space is too small, you may just need to put your content in a Scrollview.

Comment: Actually, if you scroll the page iOS hides the toolbars. Unfortunately, this means native scrolling, not the simulated scrolling of famous. I'm sure there is a JS hack available somewhere

Comment: @mark unfortunately for iOS 7 there is no JS hack. Native scrolling is the only thing that makes the header shrink and footer disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Right now there isn't a way to automagically hide browser chrome without saving to home screen with the proper meta tags for ios and android.  Alternatively, a Famo.us app can be wrapped in Cordova and distributed on AppStore and Google's Play Store, and the app will display in full screen without browser chrome.

Comment: To add to this, Mobile Safari now has support for this meta tag: 
<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui">
which hides the browser bar. See http://darkblue.sdf.org/weblog/ios-7-dot-1-mobile-safari-minimal-ui.html