# Is it possible to hide the address bar in iOS 7 Safari?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, safari, mobile-safari

Is it possible to hide the address bar in iOS 7?

I am currently using the below to do this in iOS 6 but I just updated xCode and tested in iPhone Sim and iOS 7 Safari is not responding to this.

js:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It does not work anymore. Here is a very detailed article around the  [changes in IOS7](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review)

Comment: The only workaround at this time is to tell users to download and use Google Chrome as their browser instead of Safari.

Chrome allows much better full screen support.

Comment: Can you hide the bottom bar? Or is that also off limits?

Comment: The bottom bar it hides automatically as you scroll.But you need to scroll. You cannot force a bigger size of the and hope that the the bar gets hidden. The only solution is to invite the user to add it to Home Screen. There you can have trully a full screen webapp.

Comment: soldgoldrobot's link is only a check to see if the nav and url bar are visible, not a working solution for hiding the nav and url bar.

Comment: Coming in iOS7.1 according to the Beta 2 release notes - https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2194915

Comment: @Mark The release notes seem to indicate that is an "iPhone" feature, do you happen to know if this will work on an iPad too in iOS 7.1?

Comment: @AdamChristianson The official release of 'minimal-ui' does not support iPad.

Comment: Use minimal-ui in your viewport. <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, minimal-ui”>

Comment: `minimal-ui` no longer works in iOS 8 https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014223-CH1-SW70