# ios address bar triggered when angular ui router state changes

Tags: ios, angularjs, angular-ui-router, mobile-safari, angularjs-routing

I am using Angular UI Router. Whenever I click on a link with ui-sref the address bar from ios mobile browser shows up. For example when I scroll down, the address bar hides and if I click on a link and the page transition finishes the ui address bar shows up instantly. This makes it less user friendly as the page suddenly shifts a little downwards because of the address bar.

[This website](http://www.etq-amsterdam.com) has the same issue that I have.

I have found [a website](http://www.trefectamobility.com) that doesn't have this issue although they are not using angular.

This does not happen on android chrome. And only happens in the ios safari. The version that I have tested in was ios 9.

I have tried overflow hidden but this is not the solution that I want because then the address bar is always visible.

What's triggering this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but I remember having a similar issue a while back.

I think you could add this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui”>
```

Check out these other posts: [Post 1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105589/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-address-bar-and-status-bar-in-ios-7-safari), [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890003/how-to-remove-address-bar-in-safari-in-ios).

Note: `minimal-ui` is no longer supported in iOS 8 and above ([More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889100/ios-8-removed-minimal-ui-viewport-property-are-there-other-soft-fullscreen)). However, not all users have upgraded to iOS 8, so there is still a reason to add it to your project.

Comment: Not really an answer to my question.  I am already using this, but like you already said only works on ios 7.